# CSS-only tooltips - problem w/z-index?

Tags: html, css, browser, tooltip

My goal is to use CSS ONLY for some tooltips.  I like the solution here:  http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/

The problem I'm having is when hovering over the first "qwer" (the second TD of the first TR), you can see the *second* "qwer" (second TD of the SECOND TR) over the tooltip.  I've been playing with the z-index properties of the span & the A element, but can't get it to work.

Works fine in Firefox.  IE7/8 is where I'm seeing the problem.

Any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        /*  css only tooltips via http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/  */
        a.tooltip { position: relative; color: red; }
        a.tooltip span { margin-left: -2000px; position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px; width: 200px; padding: 4px; background-color: #E2E7FF; border: 1px solid #003099; text-decoration: none; color: #000; z-index: 999; }
        a.tooltip:hover span { margin-left: 0px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td><a class="tooltip" href="#">qwer<span>asdf asdf asfd asdf asfd asdf asdf asfd asdf</span></a></td>
            <td>zxcv</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td><a class="tooltip" href="#">qwer<span>asdf asdf asfd asdf asfd asdf asdf asfd asdf</span></a></td>
            <td>zxcv</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Added my own answer below, but SO say's I can't accept it as my own for 2 days.  Anyone who can/wants to, feel free to mark it as answered, in case someone else wants an answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## SOLVED

Found the solution here:  http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/8069.htm

The key was only applying the "position: relative;" on a.tooltip:hover, not just a.tooltip .  Working code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        /*  css only tooltips via http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/  */
        a.tooltip:hover { position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0; color: red; }
        a.tooltip span { 
            margin-left: -2000px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 5px;
            top: 10px;
            width: 200px;
            padding: 4px;
            background-color: #E2E7FF;
            border: 1px solid #003099;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #000;
        }
        a.tooltip:hover span { margin-left: 0px; z-index: 999; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td><a href="#" class="tooltip">qwer<span>asdf asdf asfd asdf asfd asdf asdf asfd asdf</span></a></td>
            <td>zxcv</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdf</td>
            <td><a href="#" class="tooltip">qwer<span>qwer qwer qwer qwer qwer qwer qwer qwer qwer</span></a></td>
            <td>zxcv</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you'd included this part of the original style further down in your stylesheet, it would also have worked:

```
    * html a:hover { background: transparent; }
```